# Underscroll in RecyclerView android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I am creating a custom scroll inside `RecyclerView` and I did most of the work already but now I came to hopefully one of the last problems.

On scrolling, I am expanding/collapsing rows as they move up or down. It works fine until I reach the bottom of the list. Two items remain in their normal state because I can no longer scroll down and therefore they will not expand.

**My question is**, how can I scroll under the recyclerView when I reach the bottom? Do I need to implement onTouch listener and do the work from there? Or is there something in RecyclerView that can help me create the underscroll?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to expand them in [onOverScrolled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#onOverScrolled%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29), as that will be called at the correct time to trigger their expansion.